# Is 'console.time' in nodejs synchronous or async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

I am trying to log time for something. The general code looks like so:

```
var stream = db.call.stream();
stream.on('data', function () {
    if (first) {
        console.time('doSomething');
    }
    stream.pause();
    doSomethingWithData(data);
    if (stopCondition) {
        console.timeEnd('doSomething');
        done();
    } else {
        stream.resume();
    }
});
```

I would like to know if the call to `console.time` is blocking or asynchronous? I could not find this in the docs.

Comment: If console.time was asynchronous you couldn't measure the time elapsed between console.time and console.timeEnd because it would be impossible to know the begining of your code snippet execution. So it's necessarily synchronous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the source code of [`console.time` and `console.timeEnd`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/console.js#L79-91),

```
Console.prototype.time = function(label) {
  this._times[label] = Date.now();
};


Console.prototype.timeEnd = function(label) {
  var time = this._times[label];
  if (!time) {
    throw new Error('No such label: ' + label);
  }
  var duration = Date.now() - time;
  this.log('%s: %dms', label, duration);
};
```

They just store the starting time against the label and calculate the time elapsed since the label timed.

They don't do anything asynchronously.

**Note:** In node.js, if a function is asynchronous, it will accept `callback` as one of the parameters.